# ListBoxItem in Vertically

Tags: xaml, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

Below is my XAML code to design the horizontal menu with selection highlight.I achieved the highlighting the selected item but each item displays item take the full design

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ListboxTest" ItemsSource="{Binding ScheduleScreenItems}"  Background="Gray" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" SelectionChanged="ListboxTest_SelectionChanged" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  SelectionMode="Single">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Transparent"/>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Red"/>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <Border x:Name="myback" Background="Transparent">
                                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel  >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DayName}" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="SemiBold" Height="25" TextAlignment="Center"    Padding="0 0 0 0" Margin="0 0 0 0" Width="100" FontSize="18" Foreground="White"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"   FontWeight="SemiBold"  FontSize="18" Margin="0 10 0 0" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
                            <Line   X1="0" Y1="-70"  X2="0" Y2="50"
                                        Stroke="White"
                                  StrokeThickness="2" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Expected Menu design as [image]

But i am getting each section one by one verticaly as [image]
[image]

Please guide me to solve issue.

Comment: Add this `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"` to `ListView`

Comment: Thanks for your response @LovetoCode. I included but its not working.

Comment: Sorry You should add these too ` <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel> '

Comment: Can you specifically guide me where i have to update the code

Comment: Added answer. Please refer that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `ItemsPanelTemplate's` `Orientation` to `Horizontal`

```
<ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding ListTest}"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                     x:Name="MyListView">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Grid>
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Transparent"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Red"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <Border x:Name="myback" Background="Transparent">
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"    >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Line   X1="0" Y1="-70"  X2="0" Y2="50"
                                    Stroke="White"
                              StrokeThickness="2" />
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Can you suggest some other option

Comment: That should work. I just test. Its working. I'll add the whole code. Just check

Comment: Thank you @LovetoCode. It's working. But the list is not coming fully. Menu list has Thursday,Friday, Saturday,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday and Wednesday. In the menu design i can get upto Thursday,Friday, Saturday,Sunday,Mo. What i have to do to get full list with scroll

Comment: give  `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"` or visible  `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"`

Comment: Thank you @LovetoCode. Its working perfectly as expected